# How handle this validation context?

Tags: laravel

I have below a form for a user enter some info to do a registration in a congress.

In the form below there is this part:

```
@foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
        <input type="text" @if($customQuestion->required == "1") required @endif class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value="">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

That code shows for each ticket type the custom questions associated with that ticket type. And adds the "required" attribute if in the ticket_type_questions table the required field is "1".

My doubt is how to validate in the RegistrationController storeRegistrationInfo(), because the field might be required or not, it depends of wether is "1" or "0" in the column "required" of the ticket_type_questions table. Do you know how to handle this context?

```
public function storeRegistrationInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'email' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_question.*' => '?????'
        ]);
        ...
    }
```

Table relationships relevans for the question:

```
1 to many between congress and ticket types (a congress can have many ticket types)
1 to many between ticket types and ticket_type_questions (a ticket type can have many custom questions)
1 to many between questions and ticket_type_questions (a question can be associated with many ticket types)
```

Example of the ticket_type_questions table:

```
id       ticket_type_id       question_id        required
1               2               3                   1       (means the ticket type with id 2 has the custom question 3 and is a required field)
```

// registration form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="name"
               name="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" required class="form-control" name="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
    </div>

<!-- other form fields -->

<!-- if the all_participants is 1 in the confernece table it should appear for each selected ticket a section for the user 
    that is doing the registration insert the name and surname of each paarticipant -->
    @if (!empty($all_participants))
        @if($all_participants == 1)
            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
              @foreach(range(1, $selectedType['quantity']) as $test)
                  <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6> <!-- $k shows the ticket type name -->
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                      <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                  </div>
                   @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value="">
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
              @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif
    <input type="submit" href="#" value="Next"/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Request class using following artisan command `php artisan make:request RegisterRequest` there you could give the column the property to be nullable, which means that the user does not need to check that specific input.

The Request Class would look something like this, its basically a validation class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }
}
```

In this example the user does not have to fill the field email.

Further you just replace your Request class in your controller function parameter like this:

```
public function sent(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();       
    ....
}
```

And of course you have to import / use it properly like this:

```
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
```

Comment: Thanks but Im not understanding how that solves the issue, because the array fields participant_question[] might be required or not, it depends of wether is "1" or "0" in the column "required" of the ticket_type_questions table. Can you explain better? Even if in the registration.blade.php it appears that the custom question is required with "        <input type="text" @if($customQuestion->required == "1") required @endif class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value="">" the controller should also validate if is required or not.